# Prime Minister's Official Spokesperson (PMOS) under Boris Johnson

Tags: united-kingdom, prime-minister, boris-johnson

I know that James Slack was the last PMOS under Theresa May. Who is in this position under Boris Johnson?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 26 July 2019, it seems James Slack is Johnson's spokesman, at least for now. From [a Bloomberg article](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2019-07-26/has-u-k-s-johnson-set-preconditions-for-resuming-brexit-talks) timestamped *July 26, 2019, 7:17 PM GMT+2*:

> After the EU rejected the demands, Johnson’s spokesman, James Slack, suggested there’s little point to talks unless the bloc accepts the U.K. position.